# Keep getting the same error message using a Google Apps Script (Permission Error)

Tags: google-apps-script, permissions

I have a script that should enable us to have an hyperlink to a folderID identified by the script.

Here is the script:

> function getParentFolderName() {
> var fileId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
> var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
> var parentFolders = file.getParents();
> if (parentFolders.hasNext()) {
> var parentFolder = parentFolders.next();
> var parentFolderName = parentFolder.getName();
> Logger.log("Parent folder name: " + parentFolderName);
> return parentFolderName;
> }
> return null;
> }
>
> function getFolderId(subFolderName) {
> if (!subFolderName) {
> Logger.log("Subfolder name is null or empty.");
> return null;
> }
>
> var parentFolderName = getParentFolderName();
> if (!parentFolderName) {
> Logger.log("Parent folder name is null.");
> return null;
> }
>
> var parentFolders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(parentFolderName);
> while (parentFolders.hasNext()) {
> var parentFolder = parentFolders.next();
> var subFolders = parentFolder.getFoldersByName(subFolderName);
> if (subFolders.hasNext()) {
> var subFolder = subFolders.next();
> var subFolderId = subFolder.getId();
> Logger.log("Subfolder ID: " + subFolderId);
> return subFolderId;
> }
> }
>
> Logger.log("Subfolder not found: " + subFolderName);
> return null;
> }

Using this formula on a cell on that spreadsheet, should return a link to that Subfolder:

> =HYPERLINK("https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/" & getFolderId("Subfolder Name"), "Link Text")

However, I input the subfolder name correctly and it doesn't add any link... So I tried to have a simple formula for testing purposes:

> =getFolderId("Subfolder Name")

It returns this error message: "Exception: You do not have permission to call DriveApp.getFileById. Required permissions: (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive) (line 3)."

This seems to be the issue. I tried to add the scopes on the appsscript.json manifest file but it still doesn't work:

> "oauthScopes": [
> "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
> "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly"
> ]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, `DriveApp.getFileById` cannot be used with the custom function. It seems that this is the current specification on Google's side. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_services) I apologize for this situation. I think that in your situation, for example, when you prepare an object for searching the folder ID from the folder name beforehand, it can be used with the custom function. But, if this was not your expected result, I apologize.

Comment: Use [code fences](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to format your code. [Test formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) before posting questions.